# Regex - Get all characters after specific sequence up until specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to come up with a function which gets all the characters after "dsclid" in the current link up until an apostrophe, dollar sign or ampersand.

I am using regex and vanilla javascript to achieve this.

If dsclid is not in the current link - the function simply returns a string "NO DSCLID provided"

Unfortunately, the current function I have written is returning a syntax error and I was wondering if anyone could spot something which I cannot:

My understanding of regex is limited.

here is the function:

```
const linkChecker = () => {

const expression = /?P<dsclid>(?<=dsclid).([^&].*?)('|&|$)/
const reg = new RegExp(expression);
const params = location.href.match(reg)

console.log(params)

if (params.length >= 1 ) {
return params
} else {
    return "NO DSCLID PROVIDED!"
}
}

linkChecker();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `/(?<=dsclid)[^.$']+/` should work fine and you don't need to do `new RegExp ...`

Comment: In case of a syntax error you are supposed to include in the question. In your case it is probably because you try to build a regexp from a regexp instead of a string, so what anubhava suggests should solve your problem

Comment: Nice one, thanks that's correct.